# Adding a series of <li> tags representing attributes about a User model in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, dom, angularjs

I'm building a Django app that displays information about a user, and I want to display the user's most visited websites as a simple list of items.

To do this, I'm currently using Django's templating system to iterate over the list of websites:

```
<ul>
{% for w in top_websites %}
  <li>{{w}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, for a couple reasons (I'm thinking of switching the app to Rails later on, so it'd be nice to avoid as much Django-specific functionality in my html as possible; the Javascript on my page already receives a full json containing all the information about the user, so it would be nice to use that to generate the top websites somehow), I'd like to avoid Django templating and do this purely in Javascript instead.

What's the best way to do this?

I know I could do this in jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < topWebsites.length; i++) {
  $("ul#top_websites").append("<li>" + topWebsites[i] + "</li>")};
}
```

But this feels kind of hacky. Is there a better way? Is this what frameworks like Backbone and AngularJS (which I don't know much about and haven't used before) are for?

Comment: Please think about marking an answer as accepted... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [templating library](http://microjs.com/#templating). However if that's the only thing you have to do, using a library might be overkill.

You should always avoid dom reflows as much as possible, so instead of appending `<li>` one by one in the DOM, you could generate your whole markup and do `$("ul#top_websites").html(markup)` or you could use a `DocumentFragment`.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

$.each(topWebSites, function (index, item) {
    $('<li>').html(item).appendTo(frag);
});
$("ul#top_websites").append(frag);
```

**EDIT:**

@RichardNeilIlagan Asked a good question about using `clone` vs parsing `<li>` for each iterations. Here's  a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-clone-vs-parse) that shows some interesting results: `clone` seems to be the slowest method of all. For simplicity and since you probably won't have a long list of elements, `$('<li>')` is just fine, but using native cloning is faster `$(li.cloneNode(false))`. However if your're looking for better performances, I would not use jQuery at all...

Comment: I've been thinking all this time that it's *much* better to clone a jQuery template element, rather than having jQuery parse HTML, especially when in a loop (i.e. `var t = $('<li>'); /* in loop */ t.clone().html(item).appendTo(frag); rather than doing `$('<li>')` repeatedly. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan, Yes and you are probably right. It should be much faster to clone a node rather parsing the string over and over. Fixed!

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan, Actually I took some time to create a [**test case**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-clone-vs-parse) and cloning is actually slower.

Comment: ~ Wow. Myth probably busted then. I'll have to read around for similar cases / discussions, and I'll do my best to report back. Nice going man. :)

Answer (score 1):

MVVM libraries like Backbone and Angular allow you to represent your data (for purposes of this answer, let's take `top_websites`) in a view form (say, HTML markup). So you can definitely use them to "convert" your JS object data into HTML markup in a somewhat cleaner, more modular manner.

As much as I'd recommend you use a good MVVM library, it can be daunting when you're new to the paradigm (and you aren't familiar with a framework, like you say), and it doesn't stop you from doing the mapping yourself in plain JS. @plalx above illustrates a rather nice way of doing it.